# $_GET and isset()

Tags: php, superglobals

I am getting tried of `if isset($_GET['whatever'])...` before the rest of my if statement. E_NOTICE errors are way to handy to turn off and for `$_POST` variables I **have a solution in my init script**..

```
$POST = (is_array( $_POST ) && count( $_POST ) > 0);
```

I find this helps self posting scripts look clean.

```
if ($POST) {
    // now do something with $_POST...
}
```

I'm not sure how to dynamically do this if you have no idea what the key is? Can anyone help find a similar solution for `$_GET` variables?

**EDIT:**

I simply want `if ($_GET['whatever'] == "whatever");` to return false if it's not set and no `E_NOTICE` errors.

**EDIT:**

Sorry if I'm unclear I'm looking for a solution for `$_GET` not `$_POST`--I only am using `$_POST` as an example of what I hope to achieve.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sometimes I use a global `GET` function:

```
function GET($key, $default = null) {
    return isset($_GET[$key]) ? $_GET[$key] : $default;
}
```

Comment: Awesome.. THANKS! this'll make the code a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea of all that mess is simple: **every variable in your program should be initialized before use.**
Thus, the best you can do is to set all variables centralized, say, at the very top of your script.

But there are some different cases. For the case you posted, you need none of these but

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
```

Comment: sorry, I may be unclear.. I have a solution for $_POST but need one for $_GET

Comment: +1 for the `every variable in your program should be initialized before use.`

Comment: @Mikey1980 actually you don't have a [proper] solution for $_POST and you don't have [the same] problem with $_GET array itself, as it's already always defined and is array.

Comment: @Mikey1980 it is not true as well just learned to phrase your questions properly.

Answer (score 2):

Already answered, but since it wasn't mentioned, also try:

```
$var = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'varname');
```

That will return null if it doesn't exist, without the annoying array notices, and also filters out potential bad stuff in various ways.  See also: http://www.php.net/filter

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna have to play with that one a bit isn't clear how I'd use that in an if statement.. none the less I am curious to learn that fn

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function to do this for you.

```
function getVar($item){
    return isset($_GET[$item]) ? $_GET[$item] : '';
}
```

Then you can do `if(getVar('whatever') == "whatever")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two methods.

```
/*
* Makes any request keys into variables of the same name
*/
foreach($_GET AS $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = ($value);
}    

//Assuming a input key of $_GET['whatever'] 
echo $whatever;

/*
* Casting to an object
*/
$get = (object) $_GET;

//Assuming a input key of $_GET['whatever'] 
echo $get->whatever
```

A third option that I can think of is making the $_GET into its own class. PHP overloading is handy trick for doing this.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

I didn't feel like writing up an example demonstrating this. :)

Comment: I always wondered how to dynamically create variable names.. awesome job

Comment: Thanks! I would also recommend that in the first example you call some sort of sanitization class from inside the foreach, while in the second example you would just do it before casting to an object.

Answer (score 0):

simple I think you want to check if get value is set then need to do the next step otherwise do different

I like the first answer but need to check thats if it works for you

if(isset($_GET['whatever']){
    if ($_GET['whatever'] == "whatever");{
    //do the rest
  }
  else{
    //do the rest
  }
  }

hope it may help if what I think is your need

Answer (score 0):

- short
- no notice

  `$key = &$_POST['key'];`

This way (inside function) it is depracted, and shows error:

```
function f($s){}
f(&$_POST['key']);
```

> Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed

Answer (score -1):

When writing these sorts of scripts, I usually do something like this at the top:

```
$submitted = isset($_POST['submit']) ? true : false;
$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
$password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
(etc.)
```

Then, when testing the values, it looks something like this:

```
if ($submitted)
{
    if ($username && $password)
    {
        // do stuff with username and password including testing their values
    }
}
```

It seems to work pretty well for me.

Comment: you are writing one line of code to check for every variable, whether it is set or not, why not call a function like others have suggested?